# A way to convert bitrate/format of audio files (between upload & storage to S3)

Tags: linux, php, fedora, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

Currently using PHP 5.3.x & Fedora

Ok. I'll try to keep this simple. I'm working on a tool that allows the upload & storing of audio files on S3 for playback. Essentially, the user uploads a file (currently only allowing mp3 & m4a) to the server, and the file is then pushed to S3 for storage via the PHP SDK for amazon aws.

The missing link is that I would like to perform a simple bitrate & format conversion of the file prior to uploading the file. (ensuring that all files are 160kbs and .mp3).

I've looked into ffmpeg, although it seems that the PHP library only allows for reading bitrates and other meta, not for actual conversion.

Does anyone have any thoughts on the best way to approach this? Would running a shell_exec() command that performs the conversion be sufficient to do this, or is there a more efficient/better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance! Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the conversion and upload to S3 'outside' of the PHP application as it'll take to long for the user to hang around on the page. This could be a simple app that uses ffmpeg from the command line.

I'm not familar with linux, so perhaps someone else can provide a more specific answer, but here is the basic premise:

1. User uploads file to server.
2. You set some kind of flag (eg in a database) for the user to see that the file is being processed.
3. You 'tell' your external encoder that a file needs to be processed and uploaded - you could use an entry in a database or some kind of message queue for this.
4. The encoder (possibly a command line app that invokes ffmpeg) picks up the next file in the queue and encodes it.
5. When complete, it uploads it to S3.
6. The flag is then updated to show that processing is complete and that the file is available.

Comment: Thanks Geoff!! This is essentially the process i think i need to develop. Thank you for outlining it for me, much appreciated. I think the challenge I am trying to work out now is the upload -> que -> process method. I'm not a high level linux developer either, but it seems like this isn't a common process :)

Comment: @JonathanCoe - A low-tech/simple process might be this. Upload to server, then save the file in a specific folder. Then you have a scheduled task/command line app/service that runs every minute or so - it grabs the next file in that folder, encodes it and then moves it to another folder. Then another app (also running periodically) grabs it from that folder and moves it to S3. You could even use an app like [superflexible](http://www.superflexible.com/) fot this step.

Comment: Thanks Geoff! This makes a lot of sense, much appreciated!!